# Delete text that begin with a specific character in a txt file

Tags: text, notepad++, notepad

I have a txt file in this format (a list of numbers)

```
123456
654321
0123456
01564
98789
```

I want to delete all the lines that begins with a 0. How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `^0.*\R`
Replace with: `NOTHING`

Do not check `. matches newline`

Comment: @fas: with notepad++, type Ctrl + H

Comment: Please can you explain the regular expression `^0.*\R`. Also what if there are multiple 0's. like 00989889988, 00909090. Please explain.

Comment: @user4221591: It deletes all lines that begin with `0` so it also deletes lines begining with `00` or `00000000`.